# Feature Cursor Count on multiple layers using ArcObjects

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, arcgis-9.3

I would like to get a total count of multiple layer features (defined) within the ArcMap view extent.  The code works fine with one layer but when I add a second or third layer with an "OR" operator I only get the count of 0 because one layer may be visible within the extent but the others are not.

e.g.

```
If pLayer.Name = "Layer1" Or pLayer.Name = "Layer2"
```

Here is the code.

```
Dim pMxDoc As IMxDocument
Set pMxDoc = ThisDocument

Dim pAv As IActiveView
Set pAv = pMxDoc.FocusMap
Dim pMap As IMap

Dim pEnv As IEnvelope
Set pEnv = pAv.ScreenDisplay.displayTransformation.VisibleBounds

Dim pSF As ISpatialFilter
Set pSF = New SpatialFilter
Set pSF.Geometry = pEnv
pSF.GeometryField = "Shape"
pSF.SpatialRel = esriSpatialRelIntersects
    
Dim pEnumLayer As IEnumLayer
Dim pLayer As ILayer
```

Set pMap = pMxDoc.ActiveView.FocusMap

Set pEnumLayer = pMap.Layers

```
Dim pFLayer As IFeatureLayer
Dim pFClass As IFeatureClass
Dim pFCursor As IFeatureCursor
Dim pF As IFeature
Dim intCount As Integer
```

Set pLayer = pEnumLayer.Next

```
Do Until pLayer Is Nothing

    If pLayer.Name = "Layer1" Or pLayer.Name = "Layer2" Then '?MULITI CUR         
     
     Set pFLayer = pLayer
     Set pFClass = pFLayer.FeatureClass
     Set pFCursor = pFClass.Search(pSF, False)
            
    End If
    Set pLayer = pEnumLayer.Next
Loop

   ' Loop through the cursor and count number of selected features.
Set pF = pFCursor.NextFeature
Do Until pF Is Nothing
    intCount = intCount + 1
    Set pF = pFCursor.NextFeature
Loop

If intCount = 0 Then
MsgBox "Count = 0"
Else
MsgBox ("Count = " & intCount)
End If

pAv.PartialRefresh esriViewGeoSelection, Nothing, Nothing
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop over your features inside the loop on your layers:

```
Do Until pLayer Is Nothing
  If pLayer.Name = "Layer1" Or pLayer.Name = "Layer2" Then '?MULITI CUR         
    Set pFLayer = pLayer
    Set pFClass = pFLayer.FeatureClass
    Set pFCursor = pFClass.Search(pSF, False)
    ' Loop through the cursor and count number of selected features.
    Set pF = pFCursor.NextFeature
    Do Until pF Is Nothing
      intCount = intCount + 1
      Set pF = pFCursor.NextFeature
    Loop
  End If
  Set pLayer = pEnumLayer.Next
Loop
```

Comment: Regan, I tried the code out, but it only gave me a count of layer1 when both layers were visible.  So when layer2 is only visible the count is 0.

Comment: @artwork21, Have you ensured it is a problem with multiple layers by testing with each layer independently.  Also can you ensure it is not a problem with your specific layers by trying with other layers/datasources.

Comment: Btw, it would be more elegant to use intCount += pFClass.FeatureCount(pSF) instead of really looping over those features. HTH